# Browser slow first pageload

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari

The browser is really slow on first pageload (about 10-30 seconds), what could this be?

It's both Safari and Chrome (On OSX) and after the first pageload is done, further browsing is normal.

If the browser is closed (CMD + Q) and opened again, it's slow again.

`curl google.com` is instant though.

Answer (score 0):

The browser could be slow because it's trying to read the browsing cache from the hard drive, which could be actually slower than the network itself.

To speed up the first loading, try to clear the browser cache.

- Chrome -> [Clear browsing data](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en) (only cache)
- Safari -> [Reset Safari](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph11914)

For Safari, if you don't want to clear your history, you can [enable the Develop menu](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11926) and clear the cache from there.

Then, restart the browser.